# Вопрос по центрированию display:block

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: Сайтик]

Как сделать так чтобы кнопка с полем была в центре?

```
<div id="mainContent" class="row">
        <div class="col-4 offset-2">
            <h3>Погода в вашем городе</h3>
            <form action="" id="weatherForm">
                <label for="city">Город:</label>
                <input type="text" name="city" id="city" placeholder="Введите город" class="form-control">
                <input type="submit" name="send" class="btn btn-danger mt-2" value="Узнать">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: В центре относительно чего?

Comment: блока в котором кнопка,input